# How to make method generic, that works for all Entities?

Tags: java, generics, static

I have defined several `DeadlineEntities` in my code. Now I have a method that I want to apply to all these `DeadlineEntities`. In order not to write a method for each entity I thought to solve this generically.

### Code

```
protected Multimap<Integer, Map<String, Double>> extract() throws IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.class.getDeclaredFields();
    Multimap<Integer, Map<String, Double>> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    for (MandantKagAccountEntity mandantEntity : m_k_a_E) {
        PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity deadlineEntity = mandantEntity.getPurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity();
        if (deadlineEntity != null) {
            map.put(mandantEntity.getDb_5(), extractKagAndDeadlines(fields, deadlineEntity));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Now I have partly managed to build it up generically but I can't get any further.

### My attempt

```
protected Multimap<Integer, Map<String, Double>> extract(Class<T> clazz,                                                                                      Function<? super T, Object> func) {
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    Multimap<Integer, Map<String, Double>> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    for (MandantKagAccountEntity mandantKagAccountEntity : m_k_a_E) {

    }
    return map;
}
```

Does anyone know how I should proceed now? How do I get the object from the mandantKagAccountEntity and check if the object is not `null`?

**I would then call the method like this:**

```
protected Multimap<Integer, Map<String, Double>> getMap() {
    return this.extract(PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.class, MandantKagAccountEntity::getPurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity);
}
```

but here I get an error that the method is not static.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] with shorter names? All of these class and variable names are so long, I can't read them without scrolling; and even then, it's not clear what you're doing.

Comment: @Alberto, did u change anything? think there went something wrong?

Comment: @Andy, changed it a little bit